# AS3 - Displaying points gained above the player

Tags: actionscript-3

So, I am adding this text field to my container MC whenever a certain condition is met.

In this case, I am trying to display the number of points gained above a playerMC whenever he grabs a coin. Kind of like the old Mario Games whenever you would step on a Goomba and points would appear above the dead Goomba.

I'd like to be able to assign the "points" text field to a "Text.as" file so I could just control the text field's behaviors from there instead of from within my Document Class.

I know how to create a text field from the document class, but I can't seem to create an empty text field on the stage and then convert it into a movie clip so that I can assign it a base class.

Anyone know of a good way to handle this situation? Any ideas you might have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most efficient to just create the textField via code in the contstructor of your Text.as class. However, if you're set on doing it in the flash IDE...   create your dynamic text field, give it an instance name, then convert it to a MovieClip with F8.  Go to the library and enter you're new movieClip's properties, set the base class to your Text.as file.

Your class (which encapsulates the textField) should then start out looking something like this:

```
package {
    public class Text extends Sprite {
        public var myTextFieldInstanceName:TextField;

        public function set text(val:String):void { myTextFieldInstanceName.text = val; }
        public function get text():String { return myTextFIeldInstanceName.text;}

        public function Text(defaultText:String){
            text = defaultText;
        }
    }
}
```

In order to set the base class, you need to do the same thing that I recommended you do for your Bullet and Impact movieclips. You perform a linkage by selecting "Export to Actionscript". You can tell it what class to look at for its behavior. Then just addChild it to your playerMC (after adjusting x and y values of course).

Comment: I'd rather do the more efficient thing. I have only just started out and I have tried having subclasses initiate things without a prompt from the document class and it doesn't work. How do I even initiate the Text.as class in order to get it to create a text field?

Comment: Not understanding your question (initiate things without a prompt from the document class?)

Comment: You create an instance of your custom class the same as any other,  new Text();